# What is the best way to make animation(flash)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, actionscript

For example I want to make two eyes that close and open

1. Making the animation in the program itself(i mean using actionscript), lets say:

leftKey: method1 to Event.ENTER_FRAME and increasing or decreasing some param(x, y, width, height)

rightKey: method2 to Event.ENTER_FRAME and increasing or decreasing some param(x, y, width, height)

etc...

1. Create an animated Gif and just change the Gifs created in photoshop(many frames) when different keys are pressed, a) person walking b) person jumping, c) person sitting etc...
2. Use the Visual Frame designer in adobe flash to do the same things
3. Mix all this things, but what if the project is big enough?

Answer (score 1):

There is no best way to do anything.

There are different approaches based on projects

If a project is being done by someone good at graphics it'll be better graphically
Also if the key frames are too many its easier graphically rather than by a program

However programs are easily modifiable and you can change them should a change come up. Programs also allow more interactivity with the user easier.

Depending on what you need make a choice